# TikZ- Draw a cooking pot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce the following picture in `tikz`

[image]

I am able to draw something that looks like that but it's not the same...
Any chance to draw it or make it even more fancy?

My code is

```
\documentclass[demo]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,%
    fadings,%
    shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1cm);
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0.75) ellipse (1cm and 0.25cm);
   \draw[fill=black] (0,-1) ellipse (0.6cm and 0.1cm);
   \draw[fill=gray] (0,0.75) ellipse (0.8cm and 0.15cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

Comment: Ow, very nice! Make the biggest ellipse a little bit shorter, I mean, lower its height. Also, you can draw triangles with rounded vertices to produce the bottom.

Comment: Did you try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60697/14500 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one fairly basic variant:

[image: cauldron]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      black filler/.style={outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}}
    ]
   \path (-130:1.15 and .8) node [draw=black, rotate=-130, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25] {};
   \path (-50:1.15 and .8) node [draw=black, rotate=-50, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25] {};
    \draw [black filler] (0,0) circle (1.25 and .9);
   \draw [inner color=black!25, outer color=black] (0,0.75) ellipse (1 and 0.25);
   \path [inner color=gray, outer color=gray!75!black] (0,0.75) ellipse (0.85 and 0.175);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Here's a `pic` version. The `pic` is called `cauldron` and takes 3 arguments: the first is a size e.g. `1` or `10pt` or `2cm`; the second and third are the colours of the cauldron's contents. The size determines the *relative* size of the cauldron.

Not sure what you are cooking up, but think of Halloween....

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    cauldron filler/.style={draw=black, outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}},
    legs/.style={draw=black, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25},
    cauldron glow/.style={circular glow={fill=#1}},
    rim filler/.style={inner color=black!50, outer color=black},
    liquid/.style={inner color=#1, outer color=#1!75!black},
    pics/cauldron/.style n args=3{
      code={
        \path (-130:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-130, legs] {};
        \path (-50:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-50, legs] {};
        \path [cauldron filler] (0,0) circle (1.25*#1 and .9*#1);
        \path [rim filler] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.255*#1);
        \path [cauldron glow=#2] (0,.75*#1) circle (.75*#1 and .18*#1);
        \path [liquid=#3] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (0.825*#1 and 0.1725*#1);
      }
    }
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) pic {cauldron={1}{Silver}{gray}} ++(2.75,0) pic {cauldron={.75}{Silver}{Lime}} ++(2,0) pic  {cauldron={.5}{Chartreuse}{ForestGreen}} (-2.75,0)  pic {cauldron={.75}{Silver}{Crimson}} ++(-2,0)  pic  {cauldron={.5}{Red}{Maroon}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cauldrons]

## EDIT 2

And here's one with a rim and 'fuzzier' contents:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    cauldron filler/.style={draw=black, outer color=black, inner color=black!50, postaction={fill=black, fill opacity=.5}},
    legs/.style={draw=black, fill=black, rounded corners=2pt, isosceles triangle, minimum width=.25},
    cauldron glow/.style={circular glow={fill=#1}},
    rim drop/.style={rim filler, postaction={fill=#1!75!black, path fading=fuzzy ring 15 percent}},
    rim filler/.style={inner color=black!50, outer color=black, draw=black},
    fuzzy liquid/.style={inner color=#1, outer color=#1!75!black, path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent},
    pics/rimmed cauldron/.style n args=3{
      code={
        \path (-130:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-130, legs] {};
        \path (-50:1.15*#1 and .8*#1) node [rotate=-50, legs] {};
        \path [cauldron filler] (0,0) circle (1.25*#1 and .9*#1);
        \path [rim drop=#2] (0,0.75*#1) ++(0,-.0125*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.275*#1);
        \path [rim filler] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (.975*#1 and 0.255*#1);
        \path [cauldron glow=#2] (0,.75*#1) circle (.75*#1 and .18*#1);
        \path [fuzzy liquid=#3] (0,0.75*#1) ellipse (0.825*#1 and 0.1725*#1);
      }
    }
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path pic {rimmed cauldron={1}{Silver}{Turquoise}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rimmed cauldron with fuzzy liquid]

Comment: I love it, this should become a package :-)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks ;). I don't think this would make enough for a package but hopefully it will be useful. Or at least entertaining - maybe that would be even better ;).

Comment: What are you cooking with that glow? Is it radio active? `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar I was thinking more Harry Potter... ;). The image the OP posted reminded me of a Halloween icon created, I think, for Mac OS X: a black cauldron with glowing green contents. I assume the ingredients are eye of newt rather than uranium, although I'm not really keen on either.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[rounded corners=1ex] (-1.25,0) -- (-1.6,-1.6) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
   \fill[rounded corners=1ex] (1.25,0) -- (1.6,-1.6) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
   \draw[inner color=black!80,outer color=black] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1.4cm);
   \draw[fill=gray,line width=1.5mm] (0,1.1) ellipse (1.6cm and 0.25cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]