# Harry Potter symbols

Tags: symbols

Good evening

I have one unusual question. Are there some Harry Potter symbols in LaTeX (pictures below) ?

Thanks for an answer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `\includegraphics` ....

Comment: The Deathly Hallows one is easy enough to make I suppose, but whether it already exists I have no idea.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Creating Logo with Fancy Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145061/5764)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244368/tikz-draw-a-cooking-pot (cauldrons), http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/219610#219610 (code for a cat - there's a version sitting on Meta, too, I think and the colours can be configured to e.g. black or ginger for Hermione's or whatever). Doubtless more elsewhere - I'm only remembering the ones I've drawn, I expect.

Comment: Be aware of copyright issues for the lettering. The Deathly Hallows symbol should not reach the threshold of originality, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The second symbol is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \def\a{1cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{\a/2 * tan(30)}
    \draw[thick]
      (0, 0) -- (60:\a) -- (\a, 0) -- cycle
      (\a/2, 0) -- (60:\a)
      (\a/2, \radius) circle[radius=\radius]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A slight modification, some images show a smaller inner circle, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \def\a{1cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{\a/2 * tan(30)}
    \draw[thick]
      (0, 0) -- (60:\a) -- (\a, 0) -- cycle
      (\a/2, 0) -- (60:\a)
      (\a/2, \radius) circle[radius=\radius-.75\pgflinewidth]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The first one can also be drawn with TikZ. A grid can be put on the symbol to get the coordinates of the vertices. Easier would be to include is as image.

Answer (score 18):

There's the [Parry Hotter](http://www.1001fonts.com/parry-hotter-font.html) font. It's a TTF, so you'll need XeLaTeX to use it.

Of course, you could google for any other font and use that as well.

Comment: I can open Parry Hotter on Word 2013... Are you sure it's a TTF?

Comment: @bleh , I'm no expert on fonts or Word... but aren't you supposed to open the TTF with Windows Font Viewer ? It worked well after installation on my machine. Look in this link for more help
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Typography/TrueTypeInstall.aspx