# How to define a new triangle symbol with middle line for use as a maths operator?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, definition

I would like to use a specific symbol, a triangle with a middle line, as a mathematical operator. Here is roughly how the symbol ought to look like:

[image: Triangle with middle line]

[This was generated with `tikz` by appropriating the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331149) by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) to the question [*Harry Potter symbols*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331147)].

My intended usage has nothing to do with Harry Potter, instead I would like to use it as a unary mathematical operator that behaves well with subscripts, for instance.

**Intended syntax**

Ideally, I would define a command `\triangleline` which gives the symbol along with some code that ensures it behaves well in common mathematical environments. After this, I would define `\trilineop`

```
\newcommand{\trilineop}[1]{\operatorname{\triangleline_\mathrm{e}}{\left(#1\right)}}
```

for use in my document.

But I am not sure how to go about this, whether this is a good plan, or what would be a better plan.
Maybe there's a neat way to build this symbol out of `\triangle` somehow?

(Use of `\Delta` in undesired because the triangle sides are asymmetric in many fonts).

---

Here is an example environment which might help as a starting point.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

%Code here to define \triangleline
%%
%%

\newcommand{\trilineop}[1]{\operatorname{\triangleline_\mathrm{e}}{\left(#1\right)}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{}
      $$\trilineop{\boldsymbol{A}}$$
    \end{frame}
  
\end{document}
```

Here is the `tikz` code mentioned earlier used to generate the example image. (I used this as a black box).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \def\a{1cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{\a/2 * tan(30)}
    \draw[thick]
    (0, 0) -- (60:\a) -- (\a, 0) -- cycle
    (\a/2, 0) -- (60:\a)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not a big fan of using Ti*k*Z everywhere so I propose here a more minimal version based on good old `\bigtriangleup`. I also am not a big fan of `\left`/`\right` at all costs, so I propose a definition based on `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` from `mathtools`. The automatic scaling can be obtained with the starred version, while manual sizes can be passed as optional parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\triangleline}{\mathpalette\@triangleline\relax}
\newcommand*{\@triangleline}[2]{{%
    \sbox0{\m@th$#1\bigtriangleup$}%
    \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \ooalign{\hfil\hbox{\vrule\@width\dimen@\@height\ht0\@depth-.5\dimen@}\hfil\cr\box0}%
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mathtools}% for the following
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\trilineop}[1]{\mathop{\triangleline_{\mathrm{e}}}}{(}{)}{}{#1}

\begin{document}

\parskip=\bigskipamount

$\triangleline_{\triangleline_{\triangleline}}$

$2\trilineop{x}$

$2\trilineop[\big]{\frac{x}{2}}$

$2\trilineop*{\dfrac{x}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not ashamed to admit... This is exactly what I wished for. Thank you very much. I will accept an answer (quasirandomly) in 24 to 48 h to allow the answers to get more upvotes in the meantime.

Comment: It bothers me a little that the line is slightly off-centre.

Comment: @lesderid Rendering issue, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

%Code here to define \triangleline
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\triangleline}{\mathpalette\triangleline@\relax}
\newcommand{\triangleline@}[2]{%
  \mspace{1mu}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Delta$}\edef\a{\the\wd\z@}
    \edef\b{\the\dimexpr\triangleline@thickness{#1}}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{\a/2 * tan(30)}
    \draw[line width=\b] (0, 0) -- (60:\a) -- (\a, 0) -- cycle (\a/2, 0) -- (60:\a);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \mspace{1mu}%
}
\newcommand{\triangleline@thickness}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.4\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
  1.6\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\trilineop}{\operatorname{\triangleline_{e}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\trilineop(\boldsymbol{A})\Delta_{\mathrm{e}}(A)
\quad
\scriptstyle\trilineop(\boldsymbol{A})
\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\trilineop(\boldsymbol{A})
\]
  
\end{document}
```

Play with the factors for the line thickness until you're happy.

Don't define `\trilineop` to take an argument: supplying the parentheses makes the code cleaner; avoid `\left` and `\right` when they're not necessary, like here.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I wished for! Great answer, good to also see an option to incorporate ```tikz```. Thank you! A slight rendering difference here seems to be that the parentheses are a bit lower than is usual, I think.

Comment: @LinearChristmas The parentheses are where they use to be.

Comment: @egreg I will try to see if I can recreate it using `l3draw`, but not sure how to implement the `\fontdimen8`. Can you provide a solution with `l3draw`?

Comment: @azetina There's still no interface for this.

Comment: @egreg Fixed: I apologise for being unclear. More clearly, I meant: draw a line that intersects the top vertex of triangle, and is [parallel] to the base. Then the parentheses for the argument lie below the [parallel] line. Constrast this behavior other mathematical operators, e.g., \sin, where the argument with its parentheses lies on the middle line of the math operator.

Comment: @LinearChristmas I don't see it. You may want to make the triangle a bit smaller: `\edef\a{\the\dimexpr0.9\wd\z@}`