# Bucket of gold image/symbol

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I would like to have a nice diagram of a bucket of gold to indicate were we want to go. [image]

I have drawn an example. Is there a latex package that has such a diagram? (But then nicer than what I drew)

Comment: why do you want to draw it rather than simply include an image?

Comment: just google image search for "pot of gold" and pick one that allows re-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [that pot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244368/tikz-draw-a-cooking-pot) maybe something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.05]
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (100cm);
   \draw[fill=black] (0,75) ellipse (100cm and 25cm);
   \draw[fill=black] (0,-100) ellipse (60cm and 10cm);
   \draw[fill=gray] (0,75) ellipse (80cm and 15cm);
\draw[fill=Goldenrod, draw=orange] (70,75) ellipse (7.5cm and 4cm); 

% Gold
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{80} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{15}
\foreach \Angle in {-180,...,180}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{\a*\b/(sqrt((\a*sin(\Angle))^2+(\b*cos(\Angle))^2))} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xRand}{random(0,10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yRand}{random(0,25)}
\draw[fill=Goldenrod, draw=orange, 
shift={(\xRand,75+\yRand)}
]  (\Angle:\R)  ellipse (7.5cm and 4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! I can work with this