# Making a tikz vector drawing code from png

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, vector, tikz-graphdrawing

I have a .png image I would like to convert the edges into a vector drawing code from the path.

An example where I have seen this done is in this poster template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-ucl-poster-class-for-latex/dbgzrthjbmhf

The UCL logo is produced from a vector drawing.

What suggestions do people have to perform this task?

Comment: You can use inkscape to trace the image and then save it either in some vector format or as tikz (the later can be done with the svg2tikz extension)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60697/36296